# RxJava: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one subscriber allowed!"

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm using RxJava to calculate the normalized auto correlation over some sensor data in Android. Strangely enough, my code throws an exception ("java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one subscriber allowed!") and I'm unsure what to make of it: I know that GroupedObservables might throw this exception when subscribed upon my multiple subscribers, but I don't think I'm using such a thing anywhere.

Below you find the method that (most likely) triggers the exception:

```
public Observable<Float> normalizedAutoCorrelation(Observable<Float> observable, final int lag) {
    Observable<Float> laggedObservable = observable.skip(lag);

    Observable<Float> meanObservable = mean(observable, lag);
    Observable<Float> laggedMeanObservable = mean(laggedObservable, lag);

    Observable<Float> standardDeviationObservable = standardDeviation(observable, meanObservable, lag);
    Observable<Float> laggedStandardDeviationObservable = standardDeviation(laggedObservable, laggedMeanObservable, lag);

    Observable<Float> deviation = observable.zipWith(meanObservable, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float value, Float mean) {
            return value - mean;
        }
    });

    Observable<Float> laggedDeviation = observable.zipWith(laggedMeanObservable, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float value, Float mean) {
            return value - mean;
        }
    });

    Observable<Float> autoCorrelationPartObservable = deviation.zipWith(laggedDeviation, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float value, Float laggedValue) {
            return value * laggedValue;
        }
    });

    Observable<Float> autoCorrelationObservable = flatten(autoCorrelationPartObservable.window(lag, 1).scan(new Func2<Observable<Float>, Observable<Float>, Observable<Float>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Float> call(Observable<Float> memoObservable, Observable<Float> observable) {
            if(memoObservable == null) return observable;

            return memoObservable.zipWith(observable, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
                @Override
                public Float call(Float memo, Float value) {
                    return memo + value;
                }
            });
        }
    }));

    Observable<Float> normalizationObservable = standardDeviationObservable.zipWith(laggedStandardDeviationObservable, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float standardDeviation, Float laggedStandardDeviation) {
            return lag * standardDeviation * laggedStandardDeviation;
        }
    });

    return autoCorrelationObservable.zipWith(normalizationObservable, new Func2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float autoCorrelation, Float normalization) {
            return autoCorrelation / normalization;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one subscriber allowed!
at rx.internal.operators.BufferUntilSubscriber$OnSubscribeAction.call(BufferUntilSubscriber.java:124)
at rx.internal.operators.BufferUntilSubscriber$OnSubscribeAction.call(BufferUntilSubscriber.java:81)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.start(OperatorZip.java:210)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:154)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$ZipSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:120)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:41)
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:30)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:145)
at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:137)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7304)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.handleNewSource(OperatorMerge.java:188)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:158)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:93)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorScan$2.onNext(OperatorScan.java:110)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorWindowWithSize$InexactSubscriber.onNext(OperatorWindowWithSize.java:173)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.tick(OperatorZip.java:255)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:326)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.tick(OperatorZip.java:255)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:326)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:635)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:545)
  at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
  at rx.internal.operators.TakeLastQueueProducer.emit(TakeLastQueueProducer.java:98)
  at rx.internal.operators.TakeLastQueueProducer.startEmitting(TakeLastQueueProducer.java:45)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTakeLast$1.onCompleted(OperatorTakeLast.java:59)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorScan$2.onCompleted(OperatorScan.java:121)
  at rx.internal.operators.BufferUntilSubscriber.onCompleted(BufferUntilSubscriber.java:161)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorWindowWithSize$InexactSubscriber.onNext(OperatorWindowWithSize.java:183)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSkip$1.onNext(OperatorSkip.java:58)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
  at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.onNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:224)
  at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:121)
  at com.github.joopaue.smartphonesensing.SensorService$3.onSensorChanged(SensorService.java:102)
  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:418)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't think I'm doing anything strange here: some zips, reduces, scans and flatmaps.

Am I missing something completely obvious, is there some hidden rule that I'm breaking here or is it a bug in RxJava? Thanks!

PS. If some code is lacking for you to be able to draw your conclusions, just ask and I'll post!

Comment: What RxJava version is this?

Comment: The inner observables returned by window() are single-subscribable only too.

Comment: this is RxAndroid 0.24.0, which uses an RxJava version of +- 1.0

Comment: and I'll look into that window behaviour, that might be it :)

Comment: @akarnokd I don't think the issue's with the window operator: all occurences only have one subscriber.

Comment: One of the windowed observable might be the source to multiple sub-chains.

Comment: @akarnokd I put a `.cache()` following to all my `window(...)` statements. That should (I believe) make sure it's only subscribed to once. However, the problem still occurs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should cache the values: `window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(w -> w.cache())`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RxJava, the operators `groupBy` and `window` return an observable which can be subscribed to only once and if subscribed, they replay their accumulated contents to the sole subscriber and switch to 'hot' mode.

This was a tradeoff between returning a fully hot observable and risk missing values or return an unbounded replaying observable that allows any subscribers but retains the accumulated contents indefinitely.

The middle ground, namely a single subscriber, cold-then-hot observable is thought to be the least surprising behavior and gives the developer the option to apply further operators and pick any point between the two extremes:

```
source.window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map(w -> w.publish())
    .doOnNext(w -> w.connect())
    .subscribe(...)

source.window(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .map(w -> w.cache())
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: I know this answer is super old but it's very helpful. Do you remember where this was discussed? I'm looking for more context about this, and I can't find anything in their GitHub issues.